Sorting Issue after multiple same ITEMS
I am facing Issue while sorting 3 different items separately, i tried to explain with example.
Node/ITEM Sorting: Case 1: (If ITEM has one line number only):  we need check if this case exist, then need to check if Node/ITEM/LINE/FIER/VALUE where Key=1 is repeating in another Node/ITEM/LINE/FIER/Value where Type=Key1,if its repeating then based on ITEM/LINE/FIER/VALUE (Type=Key2) and ITEM/LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER we need to perform sorting. in my example first 3 ITEMs will has this.
Node/ITEM Sorting Case 2: (If ITEM has two or more Line numbers): condition to sort is same as above, we need to perform sorting based on similar fields, in my example 4th ITEM will has this
Node/LINE Sorting: Same as above, if Node/LINE exists then based on Node/LINE/FIER/VALUE and /EXTEN/BNUMBER, we can do sorting.
my XSLT is giving exact results, but because of 2nd condition Node/ITEM Sorting (If ITEM has two or more Line numbers), its giving me error as A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:concat() (<BNUMBER>, <BNUMBER>)  
how can i resolve this 2nd case sorting issue.
Input:
<SBD>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <Field1> value1</Field1>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <Node documentStatus="True" date="2024-09-27">
        <ship>123</ship>
        <field2>345r</field2>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>67896789</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="1">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>555</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>XYZ</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>3243</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="2">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>BBBB</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
            <Segment1>
                <subsegment>
                    <value>123</value>
                </subsegment>
            </Segment1>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>0870</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="3">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>0870</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="3">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>BBB</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
            <LINE number="4">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <LINE number="1">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>6382</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>REA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
            <EXTEN>
                <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
            </EXTEN>
        </LINE>
        <LINE number="2">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>CBA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
            <EXTEN>
                <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
            </EXTEN>
        </LINE>
        <LINE number="3">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>BCA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
            <EXTEN>
                <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
            </EXTEN>
        </LINE>
        <rdtime>123</rdtime>
    </Node>
</SBD>






Desired output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SBD>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <Field1> value1</Field1>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <Node documentStatus="True" date="2024-09-27">
        <ship>123</ship>
        <field2>345r</field2>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>67896789</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="1">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>555</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>XYZ</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>0870</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="3">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>3243</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="2">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>BBBB</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
            <Segment1>
                <subsegment>
                    <value>123</value>
                </subsegment>
            </Segment1>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>0870</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="3">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
            <LINE number="3">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>BBB</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
                <EXTEN>
                    <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                    <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
                </EXTEN>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <LINE number="1">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>6382</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>REA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
            <EXTEN>
                <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
            </EXTEN>
        </LINE>
        <LINE number="3">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>BCA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
            <EXTEN>
                <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
            </EXTEN>
        </LINE>
        <LINE number="2">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>CBA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
            <EXTEN>
                <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
                <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
            </EXTEN>
        </LINE>
        <rdtime>123</rdtime>
    </Node>
</SBD>


XSLT I used is below:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except (ITEM, LINE, rdtime)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ITEM" group-by="LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key1']/VALUE">
        <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) { 
            concat(
                $l/LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER, 
                '_', 
                $l/LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE
            )
        })" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="LINE" group-by="CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key1']/VALUE">
        <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) { 
            concat(
                $l/EXTEN/BNUMBER, 
                '_', 
                $l/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE
            )
        })" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rdtime"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>



   
        

Please review it once

How do you want to compare an ITEM that has two LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER children in terms of sorting to the ones that have only one such element?

yeah only ITEM has one BNUMBER, not more than that.

Technically, what you can do is use a sequence of sort keys generated by the third argument of the sort function e.g.
    sort(current-group(), (), function($l) {
        for-each-pair(
          $l/LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER,
          $l/LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE,
          function($b, $v) { $b, $v }
        )
    })

e.g. in context
  <xsl:for-each-group select="ITEM" group-by="LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key1']/VALUE">
    <xsl:sequence 
      select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) {
                for-each-pair(
                  $l/LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER,
                  $l/LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE,
                  function($b, $v) { $b, $v }
                )
              })
      "/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>

which outputs the ITEMs as e.g.
  <ITEM>
     <IDENT>
        <CODE>
           <Value>67896789</Value>
        </CODE>
     </IDENT>
     <LINE number="1">
        <CIDENT>
           <name>12</name>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>555</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>XYZ</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
           </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
        <EXTEN>
           <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
           <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
        </EXTEN>
     </LINE>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
     <IDENT>
        <CODE>
           <Value>0870</Value>
        </CODE>
     </IDENT>
     <LINE number="3">
        <CIDENT>
           <name>12</name>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>444</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>No</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
           </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
        <EXTEN>
           <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
           <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
        </EXTEN>
     </LINE>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
     <IDENT>
        <CODE>
           <Value>0870</Value>
        </CODE>
     </IDENT>
     <LINE number="3">
        <CIDENT>
           <name>12</name>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>444</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>No</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>BBB</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
           </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
        <EXTEN>
           <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
           <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
        </EXTEN>
     </LINE>
     <LINE number="4">
        <CIDENT>
           <name>12</name>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>444</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>No</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
           </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
        <EXTEN>
           <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
           <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
        </EXTEN>
     </LINE>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
     <IDENT>
        <CODE>
           <Value>3243</Value>
        </CODE>
     </IDENT>
     <LINE number="2">
        <CIDENT>
           <name>12</name>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>444</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
           </FIER>
           <FIER>
              <VALUE>BBBB</VALUE>
              <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
           </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
        <EXTEN>
           <BNUMBER>S123</BNUMBER>
           <Date>2025-08-15</Date>
        </EXTEN>
     </LINE>
     <Segment1>
        <subsegment>
           <value>123</value>
        </subsegment>
     </Segment1>
  </ITEM>

That is mainly meant as an example to avoid the error on the one hand and on the other to find some way to compare pair wise. I am not sure that is what you want and I have not managed to identify from your explanation or your desired output what the sort keys might be or whether you perhaps want to do some nesting grouping to eliminate duplicates.

my requirement is not to delete any duplicates, separate sorting is required.

ITEM (first 3 ITEM segments in my input is one set, because it has only one LINE inside it, so we can do the sorting based on fields i mentioned, this is working.
ITEM (4th ITEM in my input is different, because it has more than one LINE segments inside it, so we need to do sorting for this specific  ITEM using Batch number and Key2/Value.  This is not working, i think code is searching and deleting duplicates.
NODE/LINE sorting is same as step 1 i mentioned, this is working.
Apologies if i am not clear


Is "Batch number" referring to LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER? If an ITEM has two of them, which one do you want to use for sorting, simply the first one?

apologies for the confusion, you are correct its LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER,  in my input 4th ITEM has two LINE Segments in it, each LINE has its own separate BNUMBER, max occurrence of BNUMBER  is 1.

@Pavan, you still haven't explain which of the two BNUMBERs you want to use for sorting, the first one, the second one, all of them (in this case the question arises on how to compare to ITEMs which have only a single BNUMBER)?

i didn't clarified properly earlier, apologies for that.  Sorting must be same as other ITEMS sorting (1st,2nd 3rd ITEMs)
ITEM 4th Sorting:  under this 4th ITEM in input, we need to check ITEM/LINE/FIER/VALUE where Key=1 is repeating in  second ITEM/LINE occurrence, if so we need to use TEM/LINE/FIER/VALUE (Type=Key2) and ITEM/LINE/EXTEN/BNUMBER as key for sorting, else no need to do sorting.  i hope its clear.

as 4th ITEM as same  ITEM/LINE/FIER/VALUE where key=1,  sorting condition must be Key2value _Batch number,  BBB_S123 in first LINE segment, AAA_S123 in second LINE segment,  so AAA_S123 LINE Segment will be moved to first place under its parent node ITEM

I think the error occurs when sorting ITEMs, so your explanation on how to sort LINEs doesn't help. The question is how do you want to sort an ITEM (in comparison to other ITEMs) if the ITEM has two LINEs with each having a BNUMBER, do you want to sort the ITEM based of the BNUMBER of the first LINE, of the second, or both?

for your question, do you want to sort the ITEM based of the BNUMBER of the first LINE, of the second, or both?  -- > both only'
while doing this i faced error as A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:concat() (, ).
when ITEM has two or more LINE numbers, if this sorting is not possible as per my requirement, then can we ignore sorting and pass the   segment as it is.. this will work for me.

If you don't want to sort the ITEMs in a group, then remove the sort call from  <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group() ...)"/> and just use <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>. As for avoiding the error with fn:concat, well, don't use it, my answer has a code suggestion to not use concat but nevertheless use sort. But as I said, the shown code will avoid the error, so far you have failed to explain how you want to sort for that case. So either drop the sort or try the code from the answer.

ok, i need sort for ITEM which has strictly one LINE segment, for this code is working, if ITEM has two or more LINE Segments then i need pass that ITEM as it is, without any change.
If i remove sort entirely then my existing sorting will not work for ITEM which has one LINe segment.

@Pavan, you have posted code in your question that uses sort on a current-group() of ITEMs, so you will need to make up your mind how you want to sort those ITEMs and use sort in a way that doesn't throw an error. My answer has code avoiding the error. Did you try that code?

I tried your code, its working, but in the output, 4th ITEM occurrence--> its remove  all existing LINE segments under it and adding new LINE segment which is there in 2nd ITEM segment , that is the issue i am facing. please have a look

@Pavan, I have edited the answer and shown where the suggested XPath code snippet was supposed to be used and which result that gives for the ITEMs. Perhaps edit your question and show the code you have tried and the result you get if there is still a problem. I don't understand why the sort of ITEMs would remove LINEs but it is not clear anyway whether you refer to the LINEs inside of an ITEM or to the ones being a sibling.

i got the desired results with your post yesterday itself, but i missed to interpret that correctly. i sincerely  apologize for that, thank you for your patience, if any questions i will raise new question if needed, thank you so much, you are truly inspirational for the learners like me.
